# JSONSerialization works with iOS simulator but has error 'Ambiguous use of 'subscript' when using phone

Tags: ios, json, swift3

The script below worked fine using Swift 2 on both simulator on phone. Having updated to swift 3, the script works fine on simulator but throws up an error when building for phone - Ambiguous use of subscript on the following line -

```
let aObject = linkJSON[index] as! [String : AnyObject]
```

I have endeavoured to change the line to use Any, however there is no change to the error.

the full code is thus -

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var orgs: [String] = []
    var icon: [String] = []
    var address1: [String] = []
    var address2: [String] = []
    var address3: [String] = []
    var address4: [String] = []
    var postcodes: [String] = []
    var phone: [String] = []
    var email: [String] = []
    var website: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url=URL(string:"http://webdata.net/service.php")
        do {
            let allLinksData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            let allLinks = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allLinksData, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let linkJSON = allLinks["organisations"] {
                for index in 0...linkJSON.count-1 {

                    let aObject = linkJSON[index] as! [String : AnyObject]

                    orgs.append(aObject["org"] as! String)
                    icon.append(aObject["icon"] as! String)
                    address1.append(aObject["address1"] as! String)
                    address2.append(aObject["address2"] as! String)
                    address3.append(aObject["address3"] as! String)
                    address4.append(aObject["address4"] as! String)
                    postcodes.append(aObject["postcode"] as! String)
                    phone.append(aObject["phone"] as! String)
                    email.append(aObject["email"] as! String)
                    website.append(aObject["website"] as! String)
                }
            }
            print(orgs)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        catch {

        }

    }
```

It may be because its Monday, but i'm having a blank here.

Thanks

Bowcaps

Comment: you can replace `[String : AnyObject]` with `NSDictionary`.

Comment: In Swift 3 correct JSON format is `[String:Any]`,Also you need to simply specify the type of `linkJSON` as Array of Dictionary `if let linkJSON = allLinks["organisations"] as? [[String:Any]] {`

Comment: Is that the real url?

I tried building your code, and I get an error `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

Comment: @PiyushRathi `NSDictionary` makes it worse.

Comment: Russell, its a masked URL, I had forgotten to clear down the mask before posting. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you replace

```
if let linkJSON = allLinks["organisations"] {
```

with

```
if let linkJSON = allLinks["organisations"] as? [[String: AnyHashable]] {
```

Then you won't need to force unwrap the `linkJSON[index]` and you can just do

```
let aObject = linkObject[index]
```

Comment: Mark, many thanks. I had just added

as? NSArray to the same line, and achieved the results.

thanks again for the prompt assist. :-)

Comment: `as? NSArray` Don't do that. Use Swift arrays and dictionaries instead of NSArray and NSDictionary.